# bach linux file rename - how to rename multiple files in linux console

Tags: python, linux, bash, console, batch-rename

I would like to rename cca 1000 files that are named like:
66-123123.jpg -> abc-123123-66.jpg. So in general file format is:
xx-yyyyyy.jpg -> abc-yyyyyy-xx.jpg, where xx and yyyyyy are numbers, abc is string.
Can someone help me with bash or py script?

Comment: Is every prefix going to be the same (i.e. will the prefix always be 'abc')?

Comment: Also, you should really show what you've tried first per [StackOverflow's guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Every prefix is abc. "abc" is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
rename 's/(\d{2})-(\d{6})\.jpg/abc-$2-$1.jpg/' *.jpg
```

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL).

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in ??-??????.jpg ; do
    [[ $file =~ (..)-(......)\.jpg ]]
    mv "$file" "abc-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.jpg" ; 
done
```

This requires bash 4 for the regex support. For POSIXy shells, this will do

```
for f in ??-??????.jpg ; do
    g=${f%.jpg}  # remove the extension
    a=${g%-*}    # remove the trailing "-yyyyyy"
    b=${g#*-}    # remove the leading "xx-"
    mv "$f" "abc-$b-$a.jpg" ; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `rename` command, which renames multiple files using regular expressions. In this case you would like to write

```
rename 's/(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d\d\d)/abc-$2-$1/' *
```

where `\d`means a digit, and `$1` and `$2` refer to the values matched by the first and second parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to do things like this easily, is why I name my files the way I do.  Using a + sign lets me cut them all up into variables, and then I can just re-arrange them with echo.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

find *.jpg -type f | while read files
do
newname=$(echo "${files}" | sed s'@-@+@'g | sed s'@\.jpg@+.jpg@'g)
field1=$(echo "${newname}" | cut -d'+' -f1)
field2=$(echo "${newname}" | cut -d'+' -f2)
field3=$(echo "${newname}" | cut -d'+' -f3)

finalname=$(echo "abc-${field2}-${field1}.${field3}")
mv "${files}" "${finalname}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python with standard libraries:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from os import walk
from re import match
```

`Path` class will handle loginc about file parent directories, extensions, file names and etc.
`walk` may be used to traversal path tree.
And `match` will take care about searching patterns in names.

suppose we have two dirs with files:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir_1
│   ├── 66-123123.jpg
│   └── 67-123124.jpg
└── dir_2
    ├── 68-123125.jpg
    └── 69-123126.jpg
```

The following two lines of code do the trick:

```py
f = lambda p: (res:=match("(\d+)-(\d+)", p.stem)) and p.parent/("abc-" + "-".join(res.groups()[::-1]) + p.suffix)
list(map( lambda p: print(p1:=f(p)) or (p1 and p.rename(p1)),  sum( ( [ Path(r)/x for x in ds + fs ] for r, ds, fs in walk(".", topdown=False)), [] )) )
```

so now we have the following:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir_1
│   ├── abc-123123-66.jpg
│   └── abc-123124-67.jpg
└── dir_2
    ├── abc-123125-68.jpg
    └── abc-123126-69.jpg
```

Using `g` instead of `f` will do the opposite

```py
g = lambda p: (res:=match("abc-(\d+)-(\d+)", p.stem)) and p.parent/("-".join(res.groups()[::-1]) + p.suffix)
```